# Find graphene mutation/query from WSGIRequest it self

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I have a middleware class that's before the request reaches the code itself, I want to figure out what mutation/query is begin called here

```py
class CustomMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request): <--- how to figure it out using the WSGI request
        data = self.doTheMagic(request)

        if data:
           request.data = data

        response = self.get_response(request)
  
        return response
```

Comment: inspect the `request.body`/`request.path`/...?

Comment: It does appear in req.body but I have to write a parser and find the mutation from there, seems a bit sketchy doesn't it ?